# iOS app submit to Apple with document to be placed in Documents folder on install?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an application that needs a file in the documents folder.  I know it is possible to copy the file from the bundle to the documents folder when the application runs.  But I've never submitted an application to the App store and one of my coworkers thinks it may be possible to include the file with the app submission and there may be some checkbox or some way to tell the installation process to copy this file to the documents folder during installation.

Is there a way to do that?  I cannot find any information suggesting that it is possible to tell the installation process to put the file in the documents folder.  So, I'm guessing that I am stuck with writing the file the first time the application runs.  Just checking to see if App submission can enable copying a file to documents folder on installation.

Comment: A Google search for "copy file from bundle to documents directory" will yield all you can learn about this:

https://www.google.com/#q=copy+file+from+bundle+to+documents+directory

Comment: @EmilyJ - I know how to "copy file from bundle to documents directory".  Yes, I Googled and found a lot of information on that.  BUT THAT IS NOT THE QUESTION.  The question is:  Can we specify that a file should be put into the Documents folder during installation or update?

Comment: You [won't know the full path](http://aplus.rs/2013/never-save-absolute-file-paths-in-your-ios-app/) to the Documents directory until the application is installed.

Comment: Just curious, what's the aversion to copying a file out of your app bundle at first launch? Is there a technical reason, or a business reason? It's the standard way to do it. It's really easy to see if the file is there on app load and if not, copy it from your bundle.

Comment: @MikeD - You are correct.  But does Apple provide a means to specify a file to be placed in the documents folder at the tail end of the installation process?

Comment: Not that I am aware of.

Comment: @orpheist - I am creating an SDK for use by other developers.  Looking for best / easiest way I can distribute the file without requiring other developers to jump through hoops when they distribute their apps using my SDK.

Comment: @MikeD - I believe you are correct.  Just posting the question in case someone knows otherwise.  Thank you.

Comment: Oh I see - and I'm guessing it has to be a writable file, that's why it needs to be in the Documents folder? I'd still suggest doing this programatically even if Apple *can* deliver a file, particularly if that's something that customers of your SDK would have to request - that feels like more hoops to jump through than e.g. calling an initialization function in your SDK which would copy the file in place. (Which would also work in the developer's iOS simulator while they are developing their app with your SDK).

Comment: @orpheist - Good point.  Thank you.  +1

Comment: what you think is right, what your coworker is thinking is wrong... include file in app and show when app is loaded for first time...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to populate the Documents folder any other way than to copy files from your main bundle over. A new app will always have an empty Documents folder, unless some copy routine goes to work and creates files in it when the app is launched for the first time.

I know you know how to copy files from the main bundle, but just for completion:

```
// file URL in our bundle
NSURL *fileFromBundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle]URLForResource:@"yourFile" withExtension:@"txt"];

// Destination URL
NSURL *destinationURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory]URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourFile.txt"];

// copy it over
[[NSFileManager defaultManager]copyItemAtURL:fileFromBundle toURL:destinationURL error:nil];
```

http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-copy-a-file-from-the-main-bundle-into-the-documents-directory-in-ios/